# Why is my string comparison failing?

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

I am trying to read a file in C++ line by line and I have read each line into a vector. The content of the files are as follows:

```
00001010
01101010
10101011
11110111
```

I am trying to exact lines that begin with 00, 01 and 10 which works fine using the comparison below.

```
    std::string opcode = GetInstruction().substr(0,2);
    std::string fucode = GetInstruction().substr(7);

    if(opcode == "01") {
        AddInstruction(GetInstruction());
    }
    else if(opcode == "10") {
        SubInstruction(GetInstruction());
    }

    else if(opcode == "00") {
        LoadInstruction(GetInstruction());
    }
```

The part that does not seem to work is if I try and extract the line that begins with 11 and ends with a 1. For this I am doing the following comparison.

```
    else if((opcode == "11") && (fucode == "1")){
        std::cout<<GetInstruction();
        PrintInstruction(GetInstruction());
    }
```

GetInstruction returns a line from the sequence of binary numbers above such as 00001010. Nothing inside the above code block seems to run, so I am guessing something is off with my comparison but I can't see how. I have tried printing out the value of `fucode` and it prints out the correct sequence (ie 0 0 1 1) for the last character in each line.

Comment: What does `GetInstruction()` return? Does it return the same value every time you call it?

Comment: GetInstruction returns a line from the sequence of binary numbers above such as 00001010 as a string.

Comment: So when you call it two times, does it return two _different_ lines?

Comment: The first two lines of your code fragment call `GetInstruction()` twice. I wonder if `opcode` and `fucode` refer to the same instruction.

Comment: @DYZ Yes opcode and fucode refers to the same instruction for the current iteration. fucode is the last bit and the opcode is the first two.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was but I can't quite explain why. Perhaps some else can expand on it. Changing the

```
else if((opcode == "11") && (fucode == "1")){
    std::cout<<GetInstruction();
    PrintInstruction(GetInstruction());
}
```

to

```
 else if(opcode.compare("11") && fucode.compare("1")){
    std::cout<<GetInstruction();
    PrintInstruction(GetInstruction());
}
```

Seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: It might work now, because compare will return 0 if the strings are equal and a number indicating the difference otherwise (1/-1). This is likely not what you want.

Comment: Indeed, you've made it effectively equivalent to `if((opcode != "11") && (fucode != "1"))`

Comment: So I should make it `(!opcode.compare("11") && !fucode.compare("1"))`?